# how to make entry box detect letters and give warning saying "numbers only"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a GUI tkinter program for a school assignment, which requires the user to enter name, and age, and then do a quiz, my problem is when they enter their age as a string it should say please enter a number but i get this error

```
_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got
```

this is the part which concerns the age input

```
def show_frame2(self):

   try:

        if self.name.get() == "":
            self.warning.configure(text = "Please enter your name")
            self.NameEntry.focus()
        elif self.name.get().isalpha() == False:
            self.warning.configure(text = "Please enter text")
            self.NameEntry.delete(0, END)
            self.NameEntry.focus()

        elif self.AgeEntry.get() == "":
            self.warning.configure(text = "Please enter a number")
            self.AgeEntry.delete(0, END)
        elif self.age.get() > 14:
            self.warning.configure(text = "You are to old")
            self.AgeEntry.delete(0, END)
        elif self.age.get() <= 0:
            self.warning.configure(text = "Please enter a number number other than 0")
            self.age_entry.delete(0, END)
        elif self.age.get() <= 7:
            self.warning.configure(text = "Sorry, You are to young")
        else:
            self.frame1.grid_remove()
            self.frame2.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 4)
            self.next_problem()

    except ValueError:
        self.warning.configure(text = "Please enter a number")
        self.AgeEntry.delete(0,END)
        self.AgeEntry.focus()
```

Comment: Relevant [Interactively validating Entry widget content in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437)a

Comment: ***TclError: expected floating-point number but got***: [Edit] your question and show the full Traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the except ValueError into except _tkinter.TclError.

This would fix your problem.

Comment: ```During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:``` i get this error, when i use that

Comment: That's because of where the except is.

Answer (score 0):

`self.age` should probably be changed to be a `StrVar`; then do the float conversion yourself:

```
try:
    age = float(self.age.get())
except (ValueError, TypeError):
    # ... appropriate warning
```

Comment: hey bro it now detects and gives message to type a number but a valid response dosnt get get accepted